# Typescript 0.9.1 : Very slow intellisense Should i go back to 0.8.3 for better performance?

Tags: javascript, intellisense, typescript

I am now using typescript. 
While i love the language as it is way better then javascript 
i still have some issues.

My typescript compiler now eats CPU power it also takes 5 seconds to give code hinting and so on.

I was wondering was this better at older versions if so how much?

Comment: I don't experience these problems and it's fast for me .

Comment: I had these issues some months ago with VS2012, Web Essentials and 0.9. I had to move back to 0.8, found no other way. I now tried VS2013 that comes with 0.9.1, no typescript support from Web Essentials (has been removed from there) and now it works pretty fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you tried 0.9.0. They fixed the mentioned performance issues in 0.9.1

Comment: i dont think so i downloaded the newest version 3 days ago. any self experience with 0.9.1 because maybe my config is wrong

Comment: I just recorded this video today : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gjJ5vLRK8R8&hd=1 and you can see that there is no observed lag. I am using grunt (https://github.com/basarat/grunt-ts) to manage my compilation though.

Comment: thank you! i will look what the real problem is then probarly the web dev toolkit 2.9 that does not support 0.9.1

Answer (score 0):

Yes it IS!

they rewrote the compiler.
i dont know what they did wrong but they screwed it up compleately.

Until they fixed it i reccomend going back to 0.8.3.1 what is very fast!

EDIT: Maybe it is because i am using web dev toolkit 2.9 what does not officially support typescript 0.9 they removed all support in 3.0 why the hell i don't know